# How to create a moving background item

Tags: wordpress, html, css

I'm new here and I didn't know where to ask this sort of question, so here's a go. I'm trying to build my new portfolio website, and I'm trying to make it so that in the background I have a cloud that moves from left to right on the screen in the top left hand corner and it wraps around the website when it goes off the screen. How would I go about accomplishing this?

I'm building my site on wordpress, and I'm using HTML5, JS, PHP and CSS3. I tried going about using the css3 @keyframes class to move the cloud, but it didn't work.

Here's a link to my site.

http://www.secret.irmattstenquist.com

Simila sites that do this :

http://vimeo.com/   <-- With the sun and the bottom footer.

Comment: vimeo uses the mootools js library (not jquery), so my guess is they also have a mootools plugin to manipulate those objects.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsanim.com/ might be a solution. Its a javascript library for animations and you can see on their site they like animated background clouds :)

Comment: Thanks, for the example! I'm trying to make it so that I can have a cloud move from right to left on my site slowly and so it wraps around when it goes offstage.

Comment: Sadly I have not used it yet but I want to. I am also keen on seeing what it possible with CSS3, HTML5, and Javascript. Someone has mentioned parallax and I found a nice tutorial on something similar to what you might want - http://www.storiesinflight.com/html5/backgrounds-transitions.html